# Difference between ResultSet.TypeForwardOnly and ResultSet.TypeScrollable

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

what is difference between  ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY and ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE.
Since i know that forward_only is not scrollable but i wanted example that shows how forward_only moves cursor in forward direction and not scrollable and how Scroll_Insensitive is scrollable

```
      ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY
       ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY means that you can only move forward in the result set. With a scrollable cursor, you can also move backward to previously seen rows. The sensitivity (to changes) of the cursor specifies whether or not changes to previously seen rows are reflected in the result set.

The only difference between TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY and TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE is that you can move  freely around the result set with TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE. Methods like previous(), first(), absolute(n) won't throw exceptions like they would with a forward-only result set.

Comment: I am getting no exception when I use methods like previous (), first ().. for TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY and I get the output similar to TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE output.Therefore i am confused and asked the above question.

Comment: The MySQL driver (under default settings) reads the entire result set into memory and thus allows scrolling behavior even when not requested. If you look in the JDBC docs, you will see a note about exceptions on scrolling methods:"SQLException - if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed result set or the result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY"

Comment: So its Mysql which allow scrolling behaviour even when i put "Resultset.Forward_only" in createstatment() , thanks for clearing my doubt.

Comment: If you were to use the "useCursorFetch" option, this would use a prepared statement and fetch the data in chunks (fetch size). This is called a "streaming" result set and would not allow you to move backwards.